# Add middleware to an event

Tags: javascript, middleware

I've been trying to make modifications to an event handler to *intercept* it before it would normally get sent to the real event handler function.

Example:

```
var ws =  new WebSocket("/ws.ws");
ws.onmessage = function(event){
    console.log("A normal event received")
}
// or using ws.addeventlistener("message",function(){})
```

Now before the I execute the code above I would execute my middleware to intercept all event calls on the onmessage event on every websocket object that will be created in the future. The middleware would then perform a modification to the event object and then forward it to the real event.

I know how to do this with the WebSocket.send method.

```
var proxySend = WebSocket.prototype.send;
WebSocket.prototype.send = function() {
    console.log("Intercepted a send call",arguments)
    //make a change to the arguments here
    return proxySend.apply([].slice(arguments));
}
```

but I have no clue on how to do it with the message event. I believe this is impossible but it's worth a try to ask. I'm using this in a chrome extension so the middleware will always be loaded before the web page is loaded.

UPDATE:

I can do it if the website uses the addeventlistener function to add the event by using the same trick I showed in my WebSocket.send example.

For the ws.onmessage is now where I'm stuck at.

I tried to do what was suggested by using a getter/setter for the onmessage prototype.

```
var eventRef = null;
Object.defineProperty(WebSocket.prototype, 'onmessage', {
  get: function() { return eventRef ; },    
  set: function(onmessageEventHandler){ 
    eventRef = function(event){
      console.log("Before onMessage event"); // my middleware
      onmessageEventHandler(event);
    }
  }
});
```

But it does not console.log the "Before onMessage event" and it does not even call the function assigned to the onmessage event.

If you would like to test it you can try it here. I modified it to onclick for the ease of testing. https://codepen.io/MyPenAccount/pen/MWaZrwE

Comment: You could try to add a getter/setter to the existing prototype. Instead of someone setting the `onmessage` property, your function will get called with the internal plumbing.

Comment: by default , ws.onmessage=null, so you can add whatever you want.

Comment: @Evert I thought of that. The problem is that you can not access the onmessage prototype. it gives an illegal invocation error trying to access WebSocket.prototype.onmessage.

Comment: @waiaan The purpose I wanted to do this for is that this middleware is being loaded onto a website I do not own. I do not have access to ws since it would be somewhere in someone elses code. If there was a way to get the ws object when ever new Websocket() is called I may be able to find a way

Comment: @JohnSmith so how would you make your code running on the website that you do not own?

Comment: @waiaan I am writing a chrome extension which is able to inject code before the page is loaded.

Comment: @JohnSmith so you can not get the websocket instance that declared in that website ?

Comment: @JohnSmith sorry , i can not access into the chatromm

Comment: @waiaan I do not to my knowledge. I tried to look into the WebSocket.prototype.constructor but that turns out not to be called on creation of the object. I then went with getter/setter but it is just not executing anything when I assign to onmessage. I edited my post with a testing environment for this problem.

Comment: Could you completely replace window.WebSocket and proxy everything?

Comment: @Evert I think I have most of it working now. https://codepen.io/MyPenAccount/pen/QWjzaqM is what I have done. It applys a middleman to the event object. I just need to get removeEventListener working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this fully solves your issue but you can do:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "onclick", {   
    set: function(handler) { 
        // Maybe clear previous installed click handlers
        // or prevent multiple calls to this.

        this.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            alert("Middleware")

            handler(event)
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: I made a small change to the code to fix multiple reassignments https://codepen.io/MyPenAccount/pen/QWjzaqM

It does seem to do what I would want it to do. I am sleep deprived so I might be wrong but it does an exactly what it should do.

Comment: @JohnSmith Yea this is kinda what I meant too with using a setter/getter =)